# boost program_options with WinMain

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

This is my main.cpp header

```
#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
#else 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
```

I want to use program_options but this is on of the lines:

```
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
```

As you can see this line works only with gcc. How to use it with MSVC?

Comment: See if `CommandLineToArgvW` helps. It parses the command line into a form suitable for `wmain`.

Comment: Thank you it looks interesting! And for argc?

Comment: @Vinz, `argc` is "returned" in `pNumArgs`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do we have a dupe for this already? Otherwise this should be answered like from your comment.

Comment: Thank you it worked!! Please post an anwser

Comment: This is not a duplicate cause it asks specifically about boost program-options. boost program_options offers split_winmain.  The split_winmain function is a portable mechanism provided by the library. source: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.32.6.5